# Is "リア充" (Riajuu) interchangeable with "playboy"?

Tags: usage, internet-slang

I often see phrases where Riajuu appears in situations where I think it could be translated to "playboy" without any loss in meaning, following from the context and the Urban Dictionary definition.

Am I right to think that way, or does "Riajuu" and "Playboy" have a nuance in meaning?

eg.: Boy says something outgoing to a girl. Then he says to himself:
何そのリヤ充みたいなセリフ

Comment: No, not at all. Try the [Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E5%85%85).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

リア充 is different from "playboy".

**リア充**: an internet meme constructed from `リアル` (real) + `充実【じゅうじつ】` (fulfill). a person who is *successful or fulfilled in real life* (vs. an *otaku* who is living in the world of anime or video games).

In most cases this refers to someone who has a lover, used with some sense of jealousy. Sometimes this is used to refer to any "non-otaku" enjoyment outside anime/game worlds, such as skiing, parties, or going to an amusement park.

Depending on context, リア充 even includes people who are happily and busily spending their days on business (vs. [hikikomori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikikomori)).

**プレイボーイ**: a playboy, a woman chaser, a ladykiller (vs. ordinary person), just as you know in English.

Answer (score 4):

Considering they are both internet memes, "normalfag" does match リア充 pretty well.